# Read Json from server like local json file

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I am trying to parse json data from a url in the same fashion I am currently parsing from a local file for an inventory in a unity game

For the local file I use LitJson/JsonMapper to read the file from `Streaming Assets` like so:

```
itemData = JsonMapper.ToObject(File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/MyJsonFile_.json"));
```

My issue now is trying to use this method:

```
public IEnumerator GetText()
    {
        UnityWebRequest webjson =      UnityWebRequest.Get("http://mywebsite.com/MyJsonFile.json");
        yield return webjson.SendWebRequest();

        if (webjson.isNetworkError || webjson.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(webjson.error);
        }
        else
        {
            // Show results as text
            Debug.Log(webjson.downloadHandler.text);
           // itemData = JsonMapper.ToObject(File.ReadAllText(webjson.downloadHandler.text));
            // Or retrieve results as binary data
            byte[] results = webjson.downloadHandler.data;
        }
    }
```

As of yet I have not been able to use the `UnityWebRequest` and `JsonMapper` in the same way as with the local file. When I debug `Debug.Log(webjson.downloadHandler.text);` I receive back the entire contents of the json file being requested from the url. Is there a reason I can't just read the requested url file as I do with the locally hosted file?

Posting the entire script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using LitJson;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.IO;

public class ItemDatabase_ : MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<Item> database = new List<Item>();

    public JsonData itemData;



    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(GetText());


        itemData = JsonMapper.ToObject(File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/Art_.json"));

        ConstructItemDatabase();


    }

    IEnumerator GetText()
    {
        UnityWebRequest webjson = UnityWebRequest.Get("http://somewebsite.com/Art_.json");

        yield return webjson.SendWebRequest();

        if (webjson.isNetworkError || webjson.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(webjson.error);
        }
        else
        {
            // Show results as text
            Debug.Log(webjson.downloadHandler.text);


            // Or retrieve results as binary data
            byte[] results = webjson.downloadHandler.data;
        }
    }

    public Item FetchItemByID(int id)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < database.Count; i++)
            if (database[i].ID == id)  
                return database[i];
        return null;
    }

    void ConstructItemDatabase()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < itemData.Count; i++)
        {
            database.Add(new Item((int)itemData[i]["id"], itemData[i]["title"].ToString(), (int)itemData[i]["value"],
                (int)itemData[i]["stats"]["height"], (int)itemData[i]["stats"]["width"], (int)itemData[i]["stats"]["length"],
                itemData[i]["description"].ToString(), (bool)itemData[i]["stackable"], (int)itemData[i]["rarity"],
                itemData[i]["slug"].ToString()));
        }
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Stackable { get; set; }
    public int Rarity { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }
    public Sprite Sprite { get; set; }

    public Item(int id, string title, int value, int height, int width, int length, string description, bool stackable, int rarity, string slug)
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.Title = title;
        this.Value = value;
        this.Height = height;
        this.Width = width;
        this.Length = length;
        this.Description = description;
        this.Stackable = stackable;
        this.Rarity = rarity;
        this.Slug = slug;
        this.Sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Sprites/" + slug);
    }

    public Item()
    {
        this.ID = -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you specified what exact issue you are running into using this method. Does it throw an exception? Do you get null bytes back? Et cetera.

Comment: Why use web to retrieve a local file?

Comment: My issue is that I have not been able to find the right syntax to read the web json as I do the local file.

Comment: perhaps, parse the web json file is the correct terminology

Comment: @IanKemp ultimately I would like to use the json served by the UnityWebRequest in place of the

 `itemData = JsonMapper.ToObject(File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/MyJsonFile_.json"));`

I thought that would look something like 

`itemData = JsonMapper.ToObject(File.ReadAllText(webjson.downloadHandler.text)`

I get an error on that 

`path too long exception`

Comment: @IanKemp I posted the entire script as a reference as well

Comment: @BugFinder I would like to remove the need for the local file, I am using it simply as a test currently

Comment: Ok well is your web server sending the file as json? Or just text. Are you using the unity json mapper or a 3rd party? If so what is wrong with the unity one?

Comment: @BugFinder I believe it can be retrieved as text and data:
`Debug.Log(webjson.downloadHandler.text);`
 `Debug.Log(webjson.downloadHandler.data);`

I am using LitJson as I was able to accomplish what I needed with that library

Comment: What happens if you get the text to a variable and use that not repeated calls to the download handler?